# Error with importing a class from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

This is my first time asking a question so please excuse me. 
I am following a tutorial and using the code in this folder: https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_12/adding_ship_image
I literally replicated this folder in vs code with all the code and the names being used correctly. 
For some reason I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sammyawad/Documents/projects/alieninvasion/alien_invasion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ship import Ship
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ship' from 'ship' (/Users/sammyawad/Documents/projects/alieninvasion/ship.py)
```

Also, I think I have an issue with linting because it is highlighting the pygame init functions for the class even though it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```py
from .ship import Ship
```

Comment: I tried that but now I am getting a different error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sammyawad/Documents/projects/alieninvasion/alien_invasion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ship import Ship
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Also, why did you use a .ship?

Comment: do you have ```__init__.py``` in alieninvasion folder?

Answer (score 0):

import module as instance of class like this...

```
from ship import Ship as s1
```

Comment: send screen shot